# How do you flush requestIdleCallback in an Angular service test?

Tags: angular, testing, flush, requestidlecallback

I'm writing an Angular service that uses requestIdleCallback to call another function, `foo`. In my test, I want to make sure that `foo` is being called eventually.

Currently I have a test that looks like this:

```
   it('test', fakeAsync(() => {
     // Triggers a requestIdleCallback call.
     service.doSomething();

     flush();
     expect(otherService.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
   }));
```

But when I run this test, I get an error saying that `otherService.foo` was never called. I've tried replacing the flush with `flushMicroTasks()` and `tick()` with a long timer to no avail. The only thing that has worked so far was to use `done()` and add a `setTimeout` to the test itself like this:

```
   it('test', (done) => {
     // Triggers a requestIdleCallback call.
     service.doSomething();

     setTimeout(() => {
       expect(otherService.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();      
       done();
     }, 1);
   });
```

But I would like to avoid this because it could cause some flakiness. Is there anyway to guarantee that `requestIdleCallback` was flushed before I make my test assertion?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this PR comment](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/pull/938), you can define custom macroTasks to be tested by `fakeAsync` zone.

They say you have two options:

> 1. pass the options from FakeAsyncTestSpec constructor
>
>    ```
>    const testZoneSpec = new FakeAsyncTestZoneSpec('name', false, [{source: 'HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob'}]);
>    ```
> 2. sometimes application test code can't access FakeAsyncTestSpec initialize process, so user can also define a global variable before
>      load fakeAsyncTest.
>
>    [...]
>
>    ```
>    window['__zone_symbol__FakeAsyncTestMacroTask'] = [{
>      source: 'HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob',
>      callbackArgs: ['testBlobData']  // the test blob data which will be passed back to callback
>    }];
>    ```

So in your case you'd replace `source: HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob` with `source: window.requestIdleCallback`.

Comment: This looked promising but it didn't work for me. Typescript didn't find the property: `__zone_symbol__FakeAsyncTestMacroTask` on window or global so it could be an environmental issue? And setting it to the souce you suggested did not pass the test.

Comment: @Evan I'm far from being an Angular ninja, but the quote says "user can also define a global variable before load fakeAsyncTest." You have to define it, and to do it **before** you import fakeAsyncTest.

Comment: Right, I've tried to replicate the test like so: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/content/examples/testing/src/app/shared/canvas.component.spec.ts

but it did not work.